# PayPal Sandbox always shows amount of transaction is 0.01 (PayPal checkout integration)

Tags: javascript, paypal, integration

PayPal Sandbox always shows amount of transaction is 0.01
Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVzxh6XXXXXXXX9Z-1gHtNyyjBawLvnvJLRrshVSrLjwhqWoPg3FI9PiTdi-..."></script>

<div id="paypal-button-container" style="position:relative;left:25%;width:50%;text-align:center;color:#FFFF00;"></div>

<script>
paypal.Buttons().render('#paypal-button-container')

</script>
<script>
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
return actions.order.create({
"purchase_units": [
{
"amount": {
"currency_code": "USD",
"value": "35.00"
}

}
]
});
}

</script>
```

the buttons show... i click on Paypal and login to my sandbox personal account in the popup

it shows the amount of the sale as 0.01 why does it not show 35.00

What am i missing..

Thanks in advance for anyone's help

NOTE: i have tried to ask this on PayPal developer community with no response at all..i am hoping someone here on Stack Overflow can spot the problem..
I am not new coding but am new to JS

--Richard

I expected the amount of transaction to show as 35.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> paypal.Buttons().render

The button code needs to be an object inside `paypal.Buttons({...})`, as seen in [this demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) and all code samples.

Moreover, `actions.order.create` is deprecated and should not be used for any new integration; support will be sunset in the future.

Instead, create the order from a backend using the v2/checkout/orders API, on demand from a route that returns a result in JSON format. Have your buttons fetch from that backend, as seen in the demo linked above and all current PayPal code samples (notably the [Standard Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), as well as the [Integration Builder](https://developer.paypal.com/integration-builder/))